# How to find rational points on genus 2 rank 2 curves such as $y^2=x^6-4x+4$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

The question is in the title. The motivation comes from trying solving Diophantine equations in order, see [Can you solve the listed smallest open Diophantine equations?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/400714) . Because there is an algorithm for solving all equations of genus $g\leq 1$, it is natural to search for the smallest/simplest genus $2$ equations that are difficult to solve. All genus $2$ equations are hyperelliptic, that is, can be reduced to the form $y^2=P(x)$ after rational change of variables. Then Magma code

> P := PolynomialRing(Rationals());
> C := HyperellipticCurve(P(x));
> J := Jacobian(C);
> RankBounds(J);

returns the upper and lower bounds for the rank $r$ of the Jacobian. If $r\leq 1$, then $r<g$, and all rational solutions to $y^2=P(x)$ can be computed by Chabauty command implemented in Magma.

The smallest genus $2$ equation not solvable by this method is the equation $x^4-x^2+xy+y^3=0$, which transforms into the equation in the title. In this case, $r=2=g$, and Chabauty command does not work.

Comment: Maybe you can try geometric quadratic Chabauty https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.10752