# Are there integers $x,y,z$ such that $1 + x - x^3 + x^2 y^2 + z + z^2 = 0$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

In my previous question [Can you solve the listed smallest open Diophantine equations?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/400714/can-you-solve-the-listed-smallest-open-diophantine-equations) I discuss the smallest equations (in some well-defined sense) for which it is not known whether they have any integer solutions. The current smallest open is the equation $y(x^3-y)=z^3+3$, and it has three variables. Because it is open for a long time, it makes sense to leave it for now, and look for the next-smallest open ones. The next-smallest open equation in at least three variables is
$$
1 + x - x^3 + x^2 y^2 + z + z^2 = 0
$$
The question is whether is has any integer solutions.

My attempt: rewrite it as
$$
x(x^2-1-xy^2)=z^2+z+1=\frac{(2z+1)^2+3}{4}
$$
From the original equation it is clear that $x>0$. Because $z^2+z+1$ is positive and odd, both $x$ and $x^2-1-xy^2$ are positive and odd. It is known that positive odd divisors of a ``square plus $3$'' are never $2$ modulo $3$. Hence, $x\neq 2$ mod $3$. If $x=0$ mod $3$, then $x^2-1-xy^2=2$ mod $3$, a contradiction. However, if $x=1$ mod $3$ and $y=0$ mod $3$, then $x^2-1-xy^2=0$ mod $3$, so no contradiction in this case.

On the other hand, a search with $|z|$ up to 30 millions returned no integer solutions.

Comment: Slightly stronger mod restriction: x must be 7 mod 9. Note that $z^2+z+1$ is never 0 mod 9. So x must be either 4 or 7 mod 9. Since y is 0 mod 3, $y^2$ is $0$ mod 3. If $x \equiv 4$ (mod 3) , then $x^2 -1 -xy^2 \equiv 6$ (mod 9), so it must have a 2 mod 3 factor which is a contradiction.