# $y^3=x^4+x$, and computing all rational points on rank $0$ Picard curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

What are the rational solutions to the equation
$$
y^3 = x^4 + x,
$$
in particular, are there any (finite) solutions other than $(x,y)=(0,0)$ and $(-1,0)$?

Context: This is the simplest-looking example of a Picard curve, that is, curve $y^3=P(x)$, where $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree 4. The rank of its Jacobian is 0, the simplest case possible.  Hashimoto and Morrison https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.03291 treated more difficult case of rank $1$. For rank $0$, Jackson Morrow [$y^3 = x^4 + x + 2$, and existence of rational points on rank 0 Picard curves](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/407677) presented some Magma code that can prove that there are no rational points (if this is indeed the case). However, the curve $y^3 = x^4 + x$ has some rational points, so deeper analysis seems to be required. Hence the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $x = \frac{a}{d}$, $y = \frac{b}{d}$, $\gcd(a, d, b) = 1$.
$$b^3d = a^4 + ad^3$$
Suppose $p \mid a$ and $p \mid d$ for prime $p$.  Then $b$ is not divisible by $p$.
$$\nu_p(d) = \nu_p(a^4 + ad^3) = \nu_p(a) + \nu_p(a^3 + d^3) = 4\nu_p(a)$$
The last equality is true because $\nu_p(a) < \nu_p(d)$.  Hence, we can make the substitution $a = a_1c$, $d = d_1c^4$; $(a_1, d_1, c)$ are pairwise coprime.

$$b^3d_1 = a_1^4 + a_1d_1^3c^9$$
$d_1 \mid a_1$.  But this is only possible if $d_1 = \pm 1$.
$(\pm b)^3 = a_1(a_1^3 \pm c^9)$
Whence $a_1^3 \pm c^9$ must be a cube, which contradicts Fermat's theorem.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to find the simplest example that requires Picard curves theory but missed that this example can be solved by this elementary argument.

Comment: Can you find congruence obstructions for the question [Rational perfect power values of y(y+1)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/309162/rational-perfect-power-values-of-yy1) ?

Answer (score 2):

I think there are no more rational points: Write the equation as $y^3z=x^4+xz^3$ for integers $x,y,z$ where $z\ge1$ and $\operatorname{gcd}(x,y,z)=1$. We consider two cases:

- $\operatorname{gcd}(x, z)=1$. As $z$ divides $x^4$, we get $z=1$. From $y^3=x(x^3+1)$ and $\operatorname{gcd}(x,x^3+1)=1$ we get that $x^3+1$ is a cube, and we are readily done.
- $t=\operatorname{gcd}(x, z)>1$. As $t$ is relatively prime to $y$, we get $t^4\mid z$. Write $z=at^4$, $x=bt$ for integers $a$ and $b$. This yields $y^3a=b(b^3+a^3t^9)$. So $a$ divides $b^4$. But $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, hence $a=\pm1$. But $b$ and $t$ are relatively prime too, so we arrive at $\pm y^3=b^3\pm t^9$, and we finish in view of the Fermat equation for exponent $3$.